# jj = Login AttributeError: type object 'Login' has no attribute 'driver'

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler, infinite-scroll, attributeerror

Could someone please help me to solve this AttributeError? I was trying to get the page_source of a webpage that has infinite-scroll. And before getting that target page I needed to login to the target website.

Thanks.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

class Login:

    def __init__(self, log_url, target_url, user, pass_word): # comments
        # Comments
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("D:/*****/******/Downloads/chromedriver.exe") # comments
        self.reloads = 1000
        self.pause_A = 0
        self.pause_B = 15
        self.username = self.driver.find_element_by_id('email')
        self.password = self.driver.find_element_by_id('password')
        self.sleep = time
        self.lastElement = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('photo_link')
        self.log_in(log_url, target_url, user, pass_word) # Comments

    def log_in(self, log_url, target_url, user, pass_word): # comments
        #comments
        self.driver.get(log_url) # Comments
        self.username.send_keys(user)
        self.password.send_keys(pass_word)
        self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('unified_signup__label').submit()
        self.sleep.sleep(self.pause_B)
        self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL + 't')
        self.driver.get(target_url) # comments
        self.lastElement.send_keys(Keys.NULL) # comments
        # comments
        for _ in range(self.reloads):
            self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            self.sleep.sleep(self.pause_A)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jj = Login
    fun = ['https://anywebsite.com/login', 'https://anywebsite.com/lok.php', 'user', 'password']
    for tup in fun:
        log_url = tup[0]
        target_url = tup[1]
        user = tup[2]
        pass_word = tup[3]
        jj.log_in(Login, log_url, target_url, user, pass_word)
```

Comment: At which line it is failing? Please post the complete error stack. Just a thought, in `init` you are calling `log_in` before the driver fires up (?)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last): File "D:/***/***/PycharmProjects/***/02.py", line 44, in <module> jj.log_in(Login, log_url, target_url, user, pass_word) File "D:/***/***/PycharmProjects/***/02.py", line 23, in log_in self.driver.get(log_url) AttributeError: type object 'Login' has no attribute 'driver'

Answer (score 1):

In your `init()` you are calling your `log_in()` method before creating your `WebDriver`. In this method you are trying to perform a log in using the `driver` that hasn't been created yet. This results in an error saying your `Login` class doesn't have a `driver` attribute.

Move `self.log_in(log_url, target_url, user, pass_word)` to the bottom of the `init()` so you don't try to use attributes that haven't been initialized yet.

**Edit**

You're also not creating an instance of your `Login` class. `jj = Login` needs parentheses. From here on you can change `jj.log_in(Login, log_url, target_url, user, pass_word)` to `jj.log_in(log_url, target_url, user, pass_word)`.

You might want to learn the basics of `Python` programming before tackling `Selenium` with it.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/***/***/PycharmProjects/***/02.py", line 44, in <module>
    jj.log_in(Login, log_url, target_url, user, pass_word)
  File "D:/***/***/PycharmProjects/***/02.py", line 23, in log_in
    self.driver.get(log_url)
AttributeError: type object 'Login' has no attribute 'driver'

Comment: Thanks for ur replý. I do need to work on my basics; however, ur edit still gives error : jj = Login()
TypeError: __init__() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'log_url', 'target_url', 'user', and 'pass_word'

Comment: @Un_lh My bad, I'm a bit rusty aswell it seems. You're already calling `log_in` in the constructor so you don't need to do it in your `main`. Change `jj.login(.., .., .., ..)` to `Login(log_url, target_url, user, pass_word)`. Also remove `jj = Login()` from the `main`.